# How to determine caller function, file and line of a class constructor?

Tags: c++, macros

How?

I tried:

```
#define Some(p1, p2) _Some(p1, p2, __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__)
Some _Some(int p1, int p2, const char* file, const char* func, int line) { ... }
```

but:

```
some.hpp:16:12: error: macro "Some" requires 3 arguments, but only 1 given
     ~Some();
            ^
some.hpp:16:5: error: invalid use of destructor ‘~Some’ as a type
     ~Some();
     ^
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole code from line `0` to line `20` of `some.hpp`?

Comment: Your macro name is clashing with something else. This is why macro names traditionally use SHOUTY_CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

Define an entirely separate class whose job is to encapsulate source code positions. (One class, one responsibility.) This class can include functions to format the information your preferred ways.

Then define a macro, with a completely unique name, to construct the class from `__LINE__` etc.

Then your `Some` class constructor can just accept a single parameter which is the source position, and callers use the macro in each call.